# Adding ref path to required in if/then [json]

Tags: json, jsonschema

Please I need help, I have a large file which I need to validate some data. For fields under same properties it is working using code below. But I also have fields which are not under the same "properties".

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "type": { "const": "one" }
  }
   },
"then": { "required": ["test"] } }
```

So, what I'm doing is adding a reference path to the required statement. I tried this

```
"then": { "required": {"$ref" : "#/path/example" }}
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas if I can use reference path inside required and if yes how?

Comment: Please read https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html.

Comment: I did and I do understand the structure of json but I could't find a solution to this. I guess that it is valid but I don't know why it is not working (btw I wrap it inside allOf )

Comment: You can only use `$ref` where a schema is expected. `required` expects an array of strings, so `$ref` is not allowed. I'm not following what it is you are trying to do. If you edit your question with more details, then I might be able to propose an alternative schema where you don't need the `$ref`.

Comment: My problem is that the required field is not under the same path of properties "type", so how can I refer to it in the required field (I need to specify its path but as you said I cant use ref inside required). Did I explain my problem enough?

Comment: In the example above "type" and "test" are under the same "properties" but what if I want a field under #path/example to be required how to specify its path inside required. I appreciate any help

Comment: It sounds like you're new to JSON Schema, and you're making some assumptions or have some fundamental missunderstandings. It may be best to chat about this on the JSON Schema slack community (via the JSON Schema website), as it currently looks unlikely someone will be able to help you here with this sort of question. Essentially, what I'm saying is it looks like you're not asking the right question, so we'll need to dig into what you actually want to DO to understand the right question you need to ask (which we cannot do on Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to express is that if `/type` is `"one"` then `/path/example` is required.

So, these should be valid:

```
{
  "type": "one",
  "path": { "example": 42 }
}
```

```
{
  "type": "two",
  "path": { "foo": 42 }
}
```

And, this should not be valid:

```
{
  "type": "one",
  "path": { "foo": 42 }
}
```

Here's how we can do that:

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "type": { "const": "one" }
  }
},
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "path": { "required": ["example"] }
  },
  "required": ["path"]
}
```

You need to establish the path using `properties` (potentially several nested `properties` if you need to go more than two levels) and use `required` at each level.

(If I'm still no understanding your question, let me know and we can try again)